# Cant remove 404 object not found items from SharePoint 2010 crawl log

Tags: search, 404, crawling

We have a new SP2010 environment that had gone through 3-4 rounds of testing before going live. Prior to going live, the various test sites were deleted, but we've noticed that 404 Object Not Found references show up in the search crawl log.

Clicking an individual entry and selecting "Remove this item from the index" doesnt appear to have any impact, as it returns during the next incremental or full crawl of the site.

To reiterate, this is an accurate 404 message (as the test content was indeed removed), but the crawl component doesnt seem to acknowledge our request to skip the item in subsequent runs.

I've read that after three passes, the 404 will eventually be ignored, but we have well passed that threshold. Any advice or input?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

It sounds as though you have some content that has links to your test sites. Add a crawl rule that blocks those sites from being indexed. Then I suggest you reset your index and re-crawl.